# Tcp Port Open by Unknown Service

Tags: linux, port, opensuse, tcp

Running openSUSE 11.2 x86_64.

Here's what a nmap of my IP provides:

PORT       STATE SERVICE
23/tcp     open  telnet
80/tcp     open  http
**2800/tcp open  unknown**
8008/tcp   open  http

I would like to know how to view what service is causing port 2800 to be opened?

A few search engine results led me to believe that it is supposedly a port opened by a Trojan called "Theef".

If it is indeed a Trojan, what can be done to weed it out? Is my desktop's security compromised?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what do you see after running (as root):

```
nmap -sV --version-intensity 9 -p 2800 localhost
```

What makes you think you have a trojan? What have you been doing lately? And *why* are you running **telnet**?

Comment: That worked. The Port's State returns as Closed. As to your questions:
What makes you think you have a trojan? **Curiosity**.
What have you been doing lately? *Nothing noteworthy, except some basic coding.*
Why are you running telnet? *Self-Vulnerability Test?* :-).

Comment: -sV is for identifying V-ersion numbers of any services or daemons running on the host(s). It shouldn't actually *close* any already open ports. Maybe something else happened....

Answer (score 1):

The -p switch to netstat should show you what processes have what ports open:

```
sudo netstat -p
```

Answer (score 1):

`lsof` can help also:

```
sudo lsof -i TCP:2800
```

Comment: Tried that command, Port 80 returns results. Ports 23,2800,8008 refuse to do so. No results appear. Also tried `fuser -nu tcp 2800`, `fuser 2800/tcp` they also do not return anything.

Comment: I didn't know one could do that with `lsof` and `fuser`.